# How to use Chrome.tabs eventListeners in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, dom-events, event-listener

I'm fairly new to Javascript and I know I should master the basics of it before going anywhere but I would like you to explain me how `eventListeners` work. For example I want to use `chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function callback)`.

I don't really get what I should put as the callback function. I don't know if that's where I put the code that I want to execute when the event happens or not.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax. element.addEventListener(event, function, useCapture); The first parameter is the type of the event (like "click" or "mousedown"). The second parameter is the function we want to call when the event occurs. The third parameter is a boolean value specifying whether to use event bubbling or event capturing.

Well said w3Schools, this is a great resource to help you out. https://www.w3schools.com/
Hope this helps

Comment: Okay I get it but in my case the event would be creating a tab, how can I put that in the first argument ?

Comment: What kind of a tab are you wanting? Like a content tab? or a window tab? A Link?

Comment: Regular Chrome tabs (the only that you can use with chrome.tabs I think, to get URL for exemple)